# java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed [POOL-HikariCP]

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

Hello i have a problem with the connection, it is closing the connection while performing a Query. I don´t know what happens D:
Here is the configuration:

```
private static HikariDataSource Hikari;
public static String ID_Usuario;

public void connectToDatabase() {       

    Hikari = new HikariDataSource();       
    Hikari.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Hikari.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank");
    Hikari.setUsername("root");
    Hikari.setPassword(""); 
    Hikari.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
    Hikari.setConnectionTimeout(300000);
    Hikari.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    Hikari.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    Hikari.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    Hikari.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
}

public HikariDataSource getHikari(){
    return Hikari;
}
```

Now, here is the class where i used the pool, First i recieved a connection from Hikari.getConnection(). Then i saved it in "connection"

```
Pool HikariPool;
HikariDataSource Hikari;
Connection connection;

  public SQL() {
    initComponents();
  }

    public void initComponents(){
        HikariPool= new Pool();
        HikariPool.connectToDatabase();

    Hikari=HikariPool.getHikari();

    try{
       connection= Hikari.getConnection();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And i use the "connection" in validateLogin()

```
public int validateLogin(String nip){
   int validation=0;
   String SQL="SELECT * FROM bank.account WHERE No_Account='"+account+"'   
    AND NIP='"+nip+"'";
    try{
        Statement stm=Conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= stm.executeQuery(SQL);
...
```

At line " Statement stm=connection.createStatement();" an error ocurred

it says :

```
[AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-0  
- is starting.
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed at   
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection$1.invoke
(ProxyConnection.java:468)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createStatement(Unknown Source)...
```

Why is closing the connection?

Comment: The way your using the connection pool is atypical. Most connection pools revoke a connection if it is open to long, because it usually indicates that code forgot to call close (which returns it to the pool).

Comment: And please, **do not** concatenate values in a query string, use prepared statements with parameter placeholders. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I know it is different, and i´m new doing this, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

The structure of your code is rather unclear to me.  But I don't think that you want to allocate a Connection in `initComponents()`.  You should be obtaining a Connection when you need to run a query, and then closing it to return it to the pool.

Something like...

```
public int validateLogin(String nip) {
   int validation=0;
   String SQL="SELECT * FROM bank.account WHERE No_Account='"+account+"'   
    AND NIP='"+nip+"'";
    try (Connection conn = SQL.getConnection();
         Statement stm = conn.createStatement()) {
       ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(SQL);
       ...
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
       ...
    }
```

The "try with resources" will close the Connection and Statement automatically.

And where `SQL.getConnection()` does something like:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
   return Hikari.getConnection();
}
```

Comment: i know what you mean , but why can´t you open the connection before you need to run a query. why it does happen?