# java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed using HikariCP [ JPA + Hibernate + Guice]

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hikaricp

**I am frequently getting this exception** :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
    at com.inmobi.programmatics.myservice.dao.impl.AbstractDAOImpl.getByIds(AbstractDAOImpl.java:117)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1940)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1909)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection$1.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:469)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:310)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
```

Here is my configuration for using HikariCP with JPA Hibernate :

```
    JpaPersistModule jpaPersistModule = new JpaPersistModule("persistenceConfig");
    final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url",
            "jdbc:postgresql://" + configurationData.getDBHost() + ":" + configurationData.getDBPort()
                    + "/" + configurationData.getDBName() + "?stringtype=unspecified");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user", configurationData.getDBUser());
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password", configurationData.getDBPassword());
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle", "2");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", "8");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout", "30000");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", "60000");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.poolName", "master_pool");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold", "60000");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime", "600000");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.connectionTestQuery", "select 1");
    properties.put("hibernate.hikari.connectionInitSql", "select 1");
```

Here is my peristence.xml for JPA:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceConfig" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="25"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I have checked idle_in_transaction_session_timeout in postgres db is 1 hour. It means there is no issue from db side.

I have tried to adjust hikaricp configuration. But it is not helping.

Initially I thought it maybe because of leak connection for which I added **leakDetectionThreshold** to 60 sec.

Then again I thought it maybe because of getting invalid connection from pool for which I have set **connectionTestQuery**. But it's also not helping.

I have checked there is maximum 1 or 2 connection are active at any time. So it can't be maxpool size issue.

I have looked into this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027250/java-sql-sqlexception-connection-is-closed-pool-hikaricp). It is not making any sense for my problem statement as I am using entitymanager with Guice Transactional.So I don't need to care about connection closing which will take care by Guice Transactional.

Can anyone help with it ?